# Strict aliasing rules and std::copy

Tags: c++

I have a character array that contains "serialized" data that I need to interpret as 'int's. Previosuly I just cast a pointer to the location to an 'int*' and dereferenced that to get at the int data, but although it's worked well for me it's breaking the strict alias rules and therefore undefined behavour.

So now I use memcpy to copy the bytes into an int, which I believe is not undefined behavour. However can I use "std::copy"?

For example

```
char data[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int i;

std::copy(data, data+sizeof(int), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i));
```

This in itsself doesn't break the strict alias rules but any likely implementation will do so... However memcpy has the same issue and that's "allowed".

Is this standard compilant code or do I need to stick to using memcpy?

**EDIT**: I should add that I appeciate the answers on how best to do this, they are interesting, but my question was more about *is this legal* than how can I do this.

Comment: `memcpy` does not guarantee to work correctly for overlapping ranges, you need to use `memmove` for that.

Comment: I assume the OP does `memcpy(&i, data, sizeof(int))`, which does not involve overlapping ranges.

Comment: Oops - my fault. Mixed up aliasing with overlapping. *sigh*

Comment: I would use `memcpy` as that signals a low level op and saves you from the ugly cast.

Comment: @BoP Arguably, the `reinterpret_cast` signals the low-level op much more effectively than a (cast-less) `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes I likely will use memcpy, I was mostly just interested in whether this was "safe". If I use memcpy within a templated "get" function it seems to optimize the whole thing out anyway for the cases I need being both fast, and readable at the point of use :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to `std::memcpy(&i, data, sizeof(int))` and suffers the same problems of relying on endianness and the assumption that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(data)`, which are platform-dependent. `char *` is exempt from the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: char* is only except one way... You can read the bytes of another type, but you can't cast a char* TO another type and then access it. (And yes I realise this has endian problems etc, but they are not an issue for my actual application)

Comment: @JohnB: that's right, but neither `memcpy` nor `copy` needs to cast their `char*` arguments to any other type to function. They'll do a byte-for-byte copy, at least conceptually (an optimizing compiler might turn it into a faster copy).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write:

```
#if __YOU_DEFINE_IF_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define TO_INT(d) ((((int)(d)[0]))|
                  (((int)(d)[1])<<8)|
                  (((int)(d)[2])<<16)|
                  (((int)(d)[3])<<24))
#else
#define TO_INT(d) ((((int)(d)[3]))|
                  (((int)(d)[2])<<8)|
                  (((int)(d)[1])<<16)|
                  (((int)(d)[0])<<24))
#endif
```

Then, for example to get the `int` for the `{4, 5, 6, 7}` part of your code, you write:

```
i = TO_INT(data+4);
```

Note: This is not code for copy-paste, it gives an idea. If you have different systems with different sizes for `int` or may give the macro other types of pointers beside `char *`, do your own error checking.

Comment: Why would you do this? It’s horrible. If at all, use a function, not a macro, and write readable code.

Comment: Partly because my code was an example. I want to do the same thing for floats and 64 bit ints too, and it's less workable for those.

Comment: Macro/function/whatever, that's not the point. What I meant to say is you could convert the data to int by using `<<` based on the endianness of the platform rather than using `memcpy` (which THAT in fact in my opinion is horrible). Besides, the code is simple, regular with repeating components. Just some extra parentheses to make sure it doesn't _crack_ if given strange parameters. It's fairly easy to read.

Comment: If you don't like the parentheses, you could also write:
`((int)(d)[0]|(int)(d)[1]<<8|(int)(d)[2]<<16|(int)(d)[3]<<24)`
which would work fine, but I myself prefer the more parentheses heavy in fact for readability! So that whoever reads it wouldn't need to refer to the precedence table

Comment: @JohnB Right, for floats that would be a problem.

Comment: @Shahbaz Even worse, you have failed to make your point in a readable, readily understandable fashion. Your point about precedence is completely irrelevant.

Comment: While I like the idea of accessing `d[0..3]` instead of doing reinterpret casting/low level operations, this solution has several flaws: 1) It's a macro. This doesn't offer any advantages over a function but several disadvantages in this situation. Especially since you evaluate `d` multiple times which leads to problems if `d` is expensive or has side-effects. It also means it doesn't ensure that `d` has the type `char*`.

Comment: 2) You assume int has 4 bytes. I'd use a typedef that's always 4 bytes, or put in an `ASSERT` for the size of int. 3) You assume a `char` has 8 bits. While I usually make that assumption too, you might want to put in an assert for that. 4) It's very hard to read. Why not break it up into several lines?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I added a note, telling people not to copy paste and do their own error checking. You guys are real picky though. If someone asks how do I access a member of class A, given it's pointer (for example set it to 10), would you say `objptr->member = 10;` or `if (objptr != NULL) { assert(dynamic_cast<A *>(objptr) != NULL); objptr->member = 10; }`? How do you expect a beginner to learn coding with code you present with him that has double the size of actual algorithm doing error checking?

Comment: I still don't understand why you prefer a macro over a function here. A function has several advantages and no disadvantage. But the new lines made the code *much* easier to read. I have no problem with code not being production ready, but I like an answer to point out its weaknesses/where it needs more work.

Comment: If the OP is using this to deserialise information encoded in a large file and his compiler is not smart enough to `inline` a function doing exactly what I wrote, the macro works at least twice as fast. If this is used in some unzipping program, and given a huge file, you would feel the difference. You know if macros had no advantage, they wouldn't have been in C or C++.

Answer (score -1):

Does this meet your needs?

```
int f (const char* x, size_t index)
  {
  const int* p = (const int*)x ;
  return p[index] ;
  }
```

gcc 4.5.2 compiles it without any warnings, even with `-O3 -Wall` switched on.

Comment: Isn't this undefined behaviour though as you're accessing memory defined as a const char* through a pointer to a different type?

Comment: Strict aliasing allows aggressive optimisation by assuming that pointers to different types don't point to (or overlap) the same address. If there were a statement `x[99]=101;` before the `return` statement (forgetting the `const` qualifier for the moment), strict aliasing would be violated, and the compiler might return the original or the new value of `p[index]`. But that can't happen here, because `x` doesn't change.